# Simple SQL Server Profiler Event Advice

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, profiler, sql-server-profiler

I have to debug a long running SQL Server stored procedure which dynamically builds and executes queries at runtime.  I want to run a trace so I can see all of the individual pieces of SQL that are executed.

Which events will provide that level of detail?

I've been advised to use Stored Proc: RPC Completed; Batch Completed and Batch Started.  But that's only bringing back the initial execution statement.  ie. literally "exec MyStoredProcName".

Any ideas?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I don't have my laptop handy right now, but have you tried running the query management studio with the option to display actual execution plan enabled?

Comment: try SP:StmtCompleted http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189570.aspx

Comment: Both solutions revealed the SQL I was looking for, although the profiler approach is a lot cleaner as the results can easily be dumped to a table and interrogated and it doesn't generate a query plan for each statement.  Thank you both for your responses.